# C - Malloc Crash / Corrupted Heap with Pointers

Tags: c, pointers, malloc

I have a struct for a 2D LinkedList I'm making:

```
struct Node
{
    void *data;
    struct Node *up, *left, *right, *down;
};
```

Since I'm used to Java, I made a function which pretends to be a constructor which looks like:

```
struct Node* buildNode(void *data)
{
    struct Node *node = malloc(sizeof(struct Node*)); // Program crashes here.
    node->data = data;
    node->up = NULL;
    node->left = NULL;
    node->right = NULL;
    node->down = NULL;
    return node;
}
```

**My program crashes** when it reaches the `malloc` line in the second paragraph. If I remove the `*` from the `malloc(sizeof(struct Node*))`, it does not crash and works correctly.

Why is this? My `buildNode` function is simply returning a pointer to a `Node`, and is not actually returning the `Node` struct itself. The error I get has something to do with **corrupt heap** and since I am somewhat new to C, I don't understand what this all means.

thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This line:

```
struct Node *node = malloc(sizeof(struct Node*));
```

is allocating a memory block of *pointer* size (4 or 8 bytes depending on whether you're building in 32 or 64 bit mode), and returning a pointer to it. This is not what you want.

Attempting to access members of the returned object results in *undefined behavior*, such as a crash, as the memory you're hitting is outside the bounds of the allocated space. You might also silently corrupt the heap, so that later calls to `malloc` result in a crash.

Whereas:

```
struct Node *node = malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
```

is allocating a block of memory of size of `struct Node` - which is what you want.

As an aside, you should probably be checking the returned pointer isn't `NULL` before using it, then gracefully handle the error. A `NULL` would be returned if the allocation fails, for example, if you run out of memory.

Note also that C is (unlike Java) not a garbage collected language. You need to ensure that at some point you call `free` on every pointer you allocate, or the memory will not be released until the program terminates.

Comment: After a lot of studying, I've learned a lot about C and one thing that I've been told is your last statement of "or the memory will not be released until the program terminates." is not necessarily the case. Can you elaborate? A lot of places I look say that the space taken up by your application when the program quits is freed, no matter if you forgot to or not.

Comment: That's correct. The memory won't be freed *until the program terminates*, when the OS cleans up the whole process. I think you're saying exactly the same thing as me.

Comment: Oh I'm sorry I read `memory will not be released until` as `memory will not be released when`

Comment: @Hatefiend: No worries :)

Comment: I love you man. I made this silly mistake in one part of my code and I was going crazy.